# Holomorhpic Mapping from multiplly connected domain onto simply connected

Tags: complex-analysis

As I was reading some text in Riemann Mapping theorem.
There was an argument in the text that

*In general There doesnot exist holomorphic map which takes multiply connected domain onto a simply connected domain*.

I was not able to think of counter example nor the proper reasoning .

Please help.
 Thnx and regards

Comment: Maybe a more complete quote of the argument/statement from the text you got it from, as to the conditions etc., would help the post.

Comment: In the context of RMT it would also make sense to state that "*there is not **bijective** holomorphic map $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ between two domains $X,Y\subset \mathbb{C}$ of which only one is simply connected.*" This is true, because such $f$ would have to be [open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)), thus it would be a homeomorphism and simply connectedness is preserved under homeomorphisms. However, I don't know whether the satement is still true if one replaces **bijective** by **onto**.

Comment: There is another way to weaken the **bijective** condition, but this needs a little more topology: If you replace **bijective** by the three conditions **proper**, **onto** and **($f'(z)\neq 0$ for all $z\in X$)**, then the statement is still true. (This might help by ruling out possible counterexamples.) Such $f$ would have to be a covering map and hence injective on $\pi_1$, i.e. $Y$ could not be simply connected.

Comment: Sure, you should read my argument as part of a proof by contradiction. If such a map existed, then $f_*\colon \pi_1 X \rightarrow \pi_1 Y = 0$ would be injective, thus $\pi_1 X = 0$ and hence $X$ could not be multiply connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first rephrase the question:

*Let $X,Y\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and connected and $Y$ additionally be simply connected,  let $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be holomorphic. Then under which conditions on $f$ is $X$ simply connected as well?*

The question proposes that $f$ being **onto** is sufficient, this I can neither prove nor disprove. But here are some weaker results:

---

(1) If $f$ is **bijective**, then it is true.

*Proof:* Nonconstant holomorphic maps are open (by the open mapping theorem) and thus $f$ would be a homeomorphism. Simply connectedness is preserved under homeomorphisms, hence $X$ is simply connected.

---

(2) If $f$is 
**proper**, **onto** and has **nowhere vanishing derivative**, then it is also true.

*Proof:* If the derivative of $f$ does not vanish at $z \in X$, then by the inverse function theorem, there is a neighbourhood $U$ around $z$ such that $f\colon U \rightarrow f(U)$ is a diffeomorphism (even biholomorphic). Thus if the derivative is nowhere vanishing, then $f$ is a [local homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_homeomorphism). Since it is also proper and surjective, it is a covering map. But then  $f_*\colon \pi_1X \rightarrow \pi_1Y$ is injective and $\pi_1Y$ being trivial forces $\pi_1 X$ to be trivial, in other words $X$ is simply connected.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. How does one prove that $f_{*}$ is injective?

Answer (score 2):

Someone should note that it *can* happen that a holomorphic functon  maps a multiply connected domain onto a simply connected domain. For example $X=\mathbb D\setminus\{1/2\}$, $Y=\mathbb D$, $f(z)=z^2$.

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana You suspect a disk with a point removed might be simply connected?

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana It surely will be _what_? I can't tell whether you're saying it surely will be simply connected or surely will be multiply connected.

Comment: "Multiply connected" _means_ "not simply connected". Do you know what "simply connected" means?

Comment: @DavidCUllrich your  argument do seems to be correct  but the text in the book suggests that this thing is not true "in general " i.e it may be true somewhere but not always and that is what I have written in the question.